Pylance missing imports with DevContainers
I have the following folder structure
C:.
│   docker-compose.yml
│   Dockerfile
│
├───.devcontainer
│       devcontainer.json
│
└───app
        __init__.py
        main.py
        sub.py

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9 

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace
    command: sleep infinity

devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "app",
    "dockerComposeFile": "../docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "postCreateCommand": "",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "charliermarsh.ruff"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
                "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic"
            }
        }
    }
}


Everytime I try to to create a new file such as sub.py, and try to import it to main.py
main.py
from app.sub import abc

I will get this error message
Import "app.sub" could not be resolvedPylance[reportMissingImports](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportMissingImports)
(module) app

This resolve by itself if I reload the window, or rebuild the container, or pip install new libraries.
Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

In order to make pylance work in docker environment, we usually need to install the remote-ssh extension.
Make sure that the SSH service is running in your Docker container and that you can connect to the container via SSH. You must configure the SSH service for the container and set the corresponding username and password or SSH key.
After connecting to the container, you could select python interpreter by using shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and typing "Python: Select Interpreter".
